# If condition in SQLCMD script in sql database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, deployment, sqlcmd

I created Sql Server Database Project in Visual Studio and i wonder if there is possible to use something like this

pre deployment script

```
:setvar Environment Production
```

post deployment script

```
IF '$(Environment)' = 'Production'
BEGIN
    ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwTable]
    AS
        SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Production.database.dbo.Table1
    GO
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwTable]
    AS
        SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4 FROM LinkedServer.Development.database.dbo.Table2
    GO
END
```

error is : `Alter view must be the only statement in the batch.`

or simplier version

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwTable]
AS
IF '$(Environment)' = 'Production'
    SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Production.database.dbo.Table1
ELSE
    SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4 FROM LinkedServer.Development.database.dbo.Table2
GO
```

error is : `Incorrect syntax near IF. Expecting Select or With`

any idea, what is your approach ?

Comment: @Mufflix, You cannot use `IF` condition in SQL Server `VIEW`.

Comment: @Venu i know, but how to use condition with SQLCMD ? because i have different view for production and for development.

Comment: are you saying that you have SQL Server `VIEW` in `SQLCMD` mode, which has to decide which statement to execute based on the environment? I don't believe that.

Comment: @Venu why not, how else to do it ?

Comment: You cannot solve this with a view. you may need to create procedure instead. I added details as an answer below.

Comment: @Venu that does not fit my needs but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but that info must first be prefaced with:

## Don't   [image: Danger Will Robinson!]   do   [image: Danger Will Robinson!]   this!!

Your object definitions really need to be the same across all environments. Meta-data (as in config data) can be different, but not object definitions. Else you are setting yourself (not to mention the next unlucky person to take this over) up for failure. It is unmaintainable. There are differences in performance, functionality, and security between using a Linked Server and not using one. In your current setup, any QA done against this code is invalid as it isn't even close to testing the same thing in each environment.

BUT, it is understandable that there are environment-specific differences that need to be dealt with. In which case, you should have a different Linked Server definition in each environment. Don't need the Linked Server in one or more environments? That's fine, just create a "loop back" Linked Server that points at the Instance that it is currently residing in.

---

That said, you just need to bury definitions for objects requiring their own batch in an `EXEC`, such as the following:

```
IF ('$(Environment)' = 'Production')
BEGIN
    EXEC(N'ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwTable]
           AS
           SELECT Col1, Col2
           FROM Production.database.dbo.Table1;');
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC(N'ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwTable]
           AS
           SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4
           FROM LinkedServer.Development.database.dbo.Table2;');
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you write it as:

`ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwTable]
    AS
        SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM $(Environment).database.dbo.Table1
    GO`

You should be able to control the different columns too as I believe the command variables just implant text into the script before it runs.

Comment: I am using this technique elsewhere but i have problem with omitting the LinkedServer address, i updated the question. Also i think this is a workaround rather then solution, because it can be more complex sql query in the future, but thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Procedure` instead of `View` with a parameter for passing the environment. An `ALTER VIEW` statement must be the first statement of the batch, so you cannot use it in this way. Even if you somehow execute the `ALTER VIEW` statement, you will not be able to create a `VIEW. As a view is a plain`T-SQL`and cannot understand`SQLCMD` commands/variables.

The procedure may look like the one below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Results_Based_On_Environment] (@pEnvironment varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    IF @pEnvironment = 'Production'
        SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Production.database.dbo.Table1
    ELSE
        SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4 FROM LinkedServer.Development.database.dbo.Table2
END
GO
```

Comment: I only need to update existing deploy script which will execute SQL queries based on the environment. I dont want to change my database schema. The sql server does not know the development server and 'create procedure query' will fail anyway i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly what i wanted to do but it also helped me to solve the issue.
It is possible to include files, but i need manually comment/uncomment specific lines before publish.

```
:r .\included\production.views.script.sql
--:r .\included\development.views.script.sql
```

also the file can contain many `GO` statements.